# Is a user not allowed to give the bounty to himself?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounty

I put a bounty on a question of mine and later found a solution to that problem. 
I was given 0 points for the answer (obviously) but i was also not given the bounty points back when i clicked for it.

I don't really care about the points themselves, I just thought it was strange.

---

(i put the tag of "bug" because it seemed like the less wrong one - it wouldn't let me post without one of "bug feature-request discussion support")

Comment: This is interesting reading on the topic: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a link to [the bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work#16067).

From that page (updated):

> #### Can I award a bounty to my own answer?
>
> No. This used to be possible, [but it has been disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97802). The user would not get the reputation back, and the bounty will be displayed as **+0**, “this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation”.

Answer (score 15):

Why would we allow this? Think it through. This means you could start a bounty, enjoy all the privileges of promotion that a bounty confers -- and then answer and accept your own answer to get "refunded" the bounty in full.

So, that would make bounties effectively free and risk-free. Which  makes no sense...

Comment: I don't think that anyone cares about 50 points that much that he/she would try to cheat in order to get them.
I might be wrong, of course

Comment: Yes @Chriskin, I’m afraid you are wrong. There’s more than 95% nice people out there, but also more than 5% who would consider cheating. (My math here is intentional.)