# Raise visibility of self-answer by awarding bounty to self

Tags: discussion

So I posted a  <s>brilliant</s> Q and A on how to [resize partitions when you don't have physical access to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160618/how-do-i-resize-partitions-when-i-dont-have-physical-access-to-a-remote-server) as I'm seeing this happen all the time and couldn't find any specific answers here on how to do that.

1. If anyone visiting meta has posted something similar, please feel free to close it as a duplicate.
2. To raise visibility of the Q&A, I [posted a link in chat already](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51132627#51132627)

My question now becomes:

*Is it ethical / technically possible to raise a bounty on this question in a few days and if no one comes up with another <s>brilliant</s> answer, **award the bounty to myself???***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See e.g. [Is a user not allowed to give the bounty to himself?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1358/367990) linking the [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/280883) FAQ:

You can not assign bounties to yourself (any more) at all, the button should be gone. In the past (before around 2011, I think), it was possible to award the bounty, but it would always display as <kbd>+0</kbd> and return no points.

That does not mean you can not still place a bounty on the question, but you should not do it for the sake of promoting your own answer.

Also please keep in mind that linking your own posts in chat is close to the border of inviting for targeted votes, which is frowned upon, so don't do that regularly. Exceptions should be okay.

What you could do instead that seems more legitimate and beneficial for the whole site to me is to share a link to the question or answer on social media and/or external sites. There are even [badges](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/57/announcer) [for](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/58/booster) [that](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/59/publicist).